# How to custom order by enum and other columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to sort by two columns. The first column is an enum field (status) and the second is the updated_at column.

I am currently sorting by enum, shown below:

```
Car.order("
  (status = 1 DESC, updated_at DESC),
   status = 2 DESC,
   status = 3 DESC,
   status = 4 DESC,
   status = 5 DESC,
   status = 6 DESC,
   status = 7 DESC"
)
```

If there are 3 cars with a status of 1, I want those 3 cars to be sorted via the updated_at column descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment.

You can pass the SQL statement's `ORDER BY` to the `order` query method:

```
Car.order(
  'status DESC,
   updated_at DESC,
   CASE WHEN status = 7 THEN 0
        WHEN status = 4 THEN 1
        ...
        END'
)
```

Comment: That works for the example above but I want it to work if I change the order of status as well. For example if I want the status order to be (1,3,5,2,4,7)